# Create list by adding a value in by one increment, including previous

Tags: php

I have an array containing x number of values, I need to make a new array that content the first element, then the first and second, and so on:

```
$start = Array ( 
         [0] => pattern_01 
         [1] => pattern_02  
         [2] => pattern_03  
         [3] => pattern_04  
         [4] => pattern_05 
)
```

the new array containing the similar structure to this

```
$new = Array ( 
         [0] => [pattern_01]
         [1] => [pattern_01][pattern_02]
         [2] => [pattern_01][pattern_02][pattern_03]
         [3] => [pattern_01][pattern_02][pattern_03][pattern_04]
         [4] => [pattern_01][pattern_02][pattern_03][pattern_04][pattern_05]
)
```

I can use a variable increase($i++), but not how to go adding the current value including all previous.

Comment: When you say "adding the current value" do you mean addition or append as string ?

Comment: yes, string, but here it is difficult to keep adding one by one, including the previous, like the example below

Answer (score 0):

The technique you are looking for here is the use of an [accumulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulator_%28computing%29) variable to keep track of the things you have seen as you iterate over the array.

```
<?php
$start = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
$end = array();
$accumulator = '';
foreach($start as $value) {
    $accumulator .= $value;
    $end[] = $accumulator;
}
var_dump($end);
```

Output:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "ab"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "abc"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "abcd"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "abcde"
  [5]=>
  string(6) "abcdef"
}
```

This type of array -> array conversion is a nice fit for the [`array_map`](https://secure.php.net/array_map) built-in:

```
<?php
$start = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
$end = array_map(
    function($val) {
        static $accumulator = '';
        $accumulator .= $val;
        return $accumulator;
    },
    $start
);
```

It's also a possible to abuse [`array_reduce`](https://secure.php.net/array_reduce) to get the same results:

```
<?php
$start = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
$end = array();

array_reduce(
    $start,
    function($accumulator, $val) use (&$end) {
        $accumulator .= $val;
        $end[] = $accumulator;
        return $accumulator;
    },
    ''
);
```

You could use PHP's [`array_walk`](https://secure.php.net/array-walk) to modify the original array in place as well if you don't need to keep the original around for other reasons:

```
<?php
$start = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
$accumulator = '';
array_walk(
    $start,
    function(&$val, $key, &$accumulator) {
        $accumulator .= $val;
        $val = $accumulator;
    },
    $accumulated
);
```

Note the use of `&` in some callback functions to pass variables [by reference](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) rather than use PHP's default pass-by-value semantics.